# Python: capture photo from webcam with flash leds

Tags: python, camera, photo

I need to take a photo from Python in a total darkness and I intended to use an USB webcam with a LED flash for this. I tried simple *pygame* library for this but I will finish with saying that nothing useful has been found in the documentation.

Brief look at *OpenCV* (cv2.VideoCapture) doesn't give obvious hint as well.

Do you know how to "power on" those LEDs?

Comment: How do the LEDs normally flash? Regardless, it sounds like a proprietary feature that's probably triggered in the driver. Since it's not a standard feature on a lot of webcams, you probably won't find anything already written for that. But you might find something if you search for your specific camera model to see how to programmatically trigger the LEDs. My guess is that it's probably something that would have to be done at a pretty low level, though.

Comment: I don't thing PyGame or OpenCV has something like this. Maybe if you  search information directly for your webcam model then you can find something.

Comment: I'm assuming that your USB camera is powered on when data is read from it, meaning that as soon as it starts capturing data, its LEDs are lit. In which case, you can use OpenCV to capture a single frame using VideoCapture and imwrite